# Excel Matching Fields

Tags: excel

I have a file with over 1000 rows with one columns A , there is a situation when the values that are in column A have sometimes mixed order for example:

Column A

```
CAL-LA

LA-CAL
```

I need to find a solution to merge them in one in another sheet for example:

Column A in sheet 2

```
CAL - LA (double)
```

Is there any possibility to do this? I was thinking to use VLOOKUP to search for the values and also tried to change the order of words with below formula but it's also not working for me

```
RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND(" ";A2)) & " " &
```

but i could not really find the right solution. I would be very thankful for help.

Comment: Your sample uses a `-` between the two parts but your formula at the bottom uses a space.

Comment: If the data is really separated with a `-` then if you make another column with `=IF(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)>RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1))&"-"&LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))` it will swap the ones that need to be swapped and you can use that new column for your vlookup.